# "pytest" available in virtualenv, but not in travis

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

In my virtualenv with Python2.7 there is the command line tool `pytest`.

Unfortunately on travis this command is not available:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#Specifying-Test-Script

It would be great if travis would provide this command.

How to work around the missing `pytest` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pytest` executable was added in pytest 3, so you'll need to run `pip install -U pytest` first to upgrade it.

Comment: Before version 3 pytest executable was called `py.test`, otherwise you might want to try running your command with `pythonX.Y -mpytest [args]`, where X.Y is version of your python, for example `python2.7` or `python3.6`. If none of this works, it might be that pytest wasn't installed and you need to install using command above.

Comment: It's a good idea to update pytest instead of using an older version either way, though ;)

Comment: @TheCompiler I upgrade pytest via .travis.yml like this now: https://github.com/guettli/compare-with-remote/blob/master/.travis.yml Thank you for your answer.